# Python: how to merge to display as sentence and display line number

Tags: python

```
import re
line = "the heart was made to be broken"
line_split2 = re.split(r'[ \t\n\r, ]+',line)

def chunks(line_split2, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(line_split2), n):
        yield line_split2[i:i+n]

separate_word = list(chunks(line_split2, 3))

import pprint
pprint.pprint(separate_word)

count = 0
for lines in separate_word:
    count = count + 1
    print count
```

I am trying to merge list for display as sentence and display line number in front of them.

```
1 the heart was
2 made to be
3 broken
```

Any suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate()` to keep track of the line you're in:

```
for i, word in enumerate(separate_word, 1):
    print i, ' '.join(word)

> 1 the heart was
> 2 made to be
> 3 broken
```

Comment: @ThanaDaray I just updated my answer, it works with the `separate_word` list as is produced by the line `list(chunks(line_split2, 3))` in your question

Answer (score 2):

You could use `enumerate()`:

```
s = ['the heart was', 'made to be', 'broken']

for i, line in enumerate(s, 1):
    print '%d %s' %(i, line)

1 the heart was
2 made to be
3 broken
```

For more information on enumerate see http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to write your own `chunks` function. Use the `grouper` recipe from the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html), then use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) on the result of that:

```
enumerate(grouper(3, line_split2), start = 1)
```

Here's the code for `grouper`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Answer (score 0):

just use join in your for loop

```
import re
line = "the heart was made to be broken"
line_split2 = re.split(r'[ \t\n\r, ]+',line)

def chunks(line_split2, n):
 for i in xrange(0, len(line_split2), n):
    yield line_split2[i:i+n]

separate_word = chunks(line_split2, 3)


count = 0
for lines in separate_word:
    count = count + 1
    print count, " ".join(map(str,lines))

1 the heart was
2 made to be
3 broken
```